# AuthenticationException Neo4j Spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j, spark-streaming

I am using Kafka Producer and Spark Consumer. I want to pass some data in the topic as an array to the consumer and execute a Neo4j query with this data as parameters. For now, I want to test this query with a set of data.
The problem is that when I try to run my consumer I get an exception:

```
org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Unsupported authentication token, scheme 'none' is only allowed when auth is disabled.
```

Here is my main method with Spark and Neo4j configs:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("KafkaSparkStreaming")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

     val sparkConf = sparkSession.conf

    val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkSession.sparkContext, Seconds(3))
    streamingContext.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")


 val neo4jLocalConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("configs/local_neo4j.conf"))
      sparkConf.set("spark.neo4j.bolt.url", neo4jLocalConfig.getString("neo4j.url"))
      sparkConf.set("spark.neo4j.bolt.user", neo4jLocalConfig.getString("neo4j.user"))
      sparkConf.set("spark.neo4j.bolt.password", neo4jLocalConfig.getString("neo4j.password"))

val arr = Array("18731", "41.84000015258789", "-87.62999725341797")
    execNeo4jSearchQuery(arr, sparkSession.sparkContext)

    streamingContext.start()
    streamingContext.awaitTermination()
```

}

And this is the method in which I run my query:

```
def execNeo4jSearchQuery(data: Array[String], sc: SparkContext) = {
      println("Id: " + data(0) + ", Lat: " + data(1) + ", Lon: " + data(2))
      val neo = Neo4j(sc)
      val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
      val query = "MATCH (m:Member)-[mtg_r:MT_TO_MEMBER]->(mt:MemberTopics)-[mtt_r:MT_TO_TOPIC]->(t:Topic), (t1:Topic)-[tt_r:GT_TO_TOPIC]->(gt:GroupTopics)-[tg_r:GT_TO_GROUP]->(g:Group)-[h_r:HAS]->(e:Event)-[a_r:AT]->(v:Venue) WHERE mt.topic_id = gt.topic_id AND distance(point({ longitude: {lon}, latitude: {lat}}),point({ longitude: v.lon, latitude: v.lat })) < 4000 AND mt.member_id = {id} RETURN g.group_name, e.event_name, v.venue_name"

    val df = neo.cypher(query).params(Map("lat" -> data(1).toDouble, "lon" -> data(2).toDouble, "id" -> data(0).toInt))
      .partitions(4).batch(25)
      .loadDataFrame
}
```

I checked the query it works fine in Neo4j. So what may cause this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched and tried various options that helped me find an answer. AS I understood this exception happens because I do not set SparkConfig parameters for Neo4j properly. And the solutions would be to provide the SparkConfig as one of the SparkSession attributes. SparkConfig should already have all the Neo4j attributes set up